When a child process is terminated by a signal, how can I tell which process sent the signal, from the parent process?
In the parent process, I used waitpid() to wait for its child process to exit, and the macros like WIFEXITED, WIFSIGNALED and WTERMSIG to determine the reason for exit. I also have to figure out which process sent the signal; how can I do so?
I want to determine which process sent the signal that made the child process terminate.

Create your child signal handler using SA_SIGINFO - see here for a description.  This will pass your child the process ID of the process that sent the signal in the siginfo_t structure.
You then just need to decide how you want to pass that back to the parent process.  That's up to you, but a simple way to do it would be by saving the details to a file (or maybe stderr?).
